# Determine $\sum \frac{a_n}{n\sqrt{n}}$ converge or not

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

**Problem :**

Determine $$\sum_1 \frac{a_n}{n\sqrt{n}}$$

converge or not where
$$\sum_1 (-1)^n a_n$$
converge.

---

It seems converge intuitively because the series $\sum (-1)^na_n$ converges,

this implies $a_n \to 0$.

Since $\sum \frac{1}{n\sqrt{n}}$ also converges, this implies

$$\frac{a_n}{n\sqrt{n}}$$ decays faster than $\frac{1}{n}$, so I think $\sum \frac{a_n}{n\sqrt{n}}$ converges.

But how can I get assurance about this? (or counterexamples?)

Comment: If you know that $a_n \rightarrow 0$, then this implies that this is a bounded sequence, e.g. bounded by some constant $C>0$. You claim you already know that $\sum \frac{C}{n^{3/2}}$ converges, so..

Comment: Note that your ideas can be used to prove absolute convergence of the given series. Since $a_n\to0$ there is $N$ such that for all $n>N$ you have $|a_n|<1$. Then $|a_n/(n^{3/2})|<n^{-3/2}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a slightly more formal restatement of your argument:

Since $\sum (-1)^na_n$ converges, $a_n \to 0$. Therefore, there exists some $N \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $0 \leq |a_n| \leq 1$ for all $n \geq N$. Consequently,

$$\sum_{k = N}^\infty \left | \frac{a_k}{k^{3/2}} \right | \leq \sum_{k = N}^\infty \frac{1}{k^{3/2}}$$.

By the $p$-test, the series on the right hand side of the inequality converges, so by the comparison test, the series on the left converges as well. Since $\sum_{k = N}^\infty \frac{a_k}{k^{3/2}}$ converges absolutely, it converges. Finally, the original series $\sum_{n = 1}^\infty \frac{a_n}{n^{3/2}}$ only differs from by the sum of $\sum_{k = N}^\infty \frac{a_k}{k^{3/2}}$ by the first $N - 1$ terms, which is a finite sum. So the series converges.